# Laravel Validation - Individual rule and individual field problem

Tags: laravel, validation

i have a field in Laravel with the name "company_url". and its stored like this.

```
$post['company_url'] = "http://example.org";
```

and then i have a rule string which i have stored for validation which must be applied on this individual field. which is stored like this

```
   $post['rule'] = "required|max:24";
```

now i am trying this code to get validation errors. which is not working.

```
    $validator = Validator::make([$post['name']], [$post['rules']]);
```

tell me what is the way to get errors on this validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you're passing to `make()` is in incorrect format. It should be in key-value pair format.

Also I don't know where the `$post['name']` coming from. I assume it is `company_url` not `name`.

`$post['rules']` is also undefined. It should be `$post['rule']`

The following should work:

```
$validator = Validator::make(['company_url' => $post['company_url']], ['company_url' => $post['rule']]);
```